# How CIBIL Credit score will impact for 2 unsecured loans?

Tags: india, loans, credit-score, credit-report, personal-loan

I have 2 loans. One I am  paying on time correctly. Another one I am paying partially.

How it will affect my CIBIL Credit score?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will impact your score negatively. The score looks at all the Loans. There should be moderate amount and number of loans. The another aspect is ALL loans should be paid ON-TIME and in FULL.

If you are paying partly on one loan, it will drag the overall score down. By how much would depend on the loan amount and the time it is over due.

It would be best if you talk to your bank and ask them to re-amortize to a lower amount and longer duration. This would then start to improve the score.

**Edit**

1. Not Paying a loan will definitely reduce your score.
2. Taking another loan, provided someone will grant you the loan [with a poor credit score, you may not get another loan], will just replace the bad loan as closed.
3. If you can't pay the second loan, what makes you think you can pay the new loan? If you default, it would look like default on old loan plus a default on new loan.
4. As suggested earlier, it is best you start paying the second loan regularly to see an improvement in your score.

Comment: fine thanks. Which will increase cibil?.1. Not paying one loan. 2. taking another loan and paying 2nd loan fully and first loan partially.